# Почему не всякий раз срабатывает событие click во фрейме?

Tags: iframe, click

Запускаю страницу:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Frames</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <p>Два фрейма</p>
 <iframe src="a.html" name="A"></iframe>
 <iframe src="b.html" name="B"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Она имеет соответственно два фрейма.

Фрейм "А":

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>A Frame</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Фрейм A</p>
 <a href='#1'>f2</a>
 <script>
  var f2 = parent.B.f;
  var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  aTag[0].addEventListener('click', f2, false);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

и фрейм "В":

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>B Frame</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Фрейм B</p>
 <a href='#2'>f</a>
 <p id='res'></p>
 <script>
  var x = 10;
  var y = 11;
  var xy = 0;
  var resHtml = document.getElementById('res');
  function f(){
   resHtml.innerHTML = xy;
   xy = x + y;
   x++;
   y++;
   return xy;
  }
  var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  aTag[0].addEventListener('click', f, false); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

По идее при нажатии на ссылку, находящуюся во фрейме "А",

```html
<a href='#1'>f2</a>
```

должно сработать событие click и запустить функцию, что находится во фрейме "В". Однако это событие срабатывает не всякий раз. При перезагрузке страницы может сработать, а может не сработать.

Событие click во фрейме "В" работает стабильно.

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Почему событие срабатывает "через раз"?

Comment: Вот скажите, кто молча минусует вопросы? Что вас не устраивает? Текст вопроса - грамотный, весь требуемый код - приведен, усилия для воспроизведения нужны минимальные. Хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это довольно просто. Страницы во фреймах загружаются в произвольном порядке. В некоторых случаях во время выполнения кода в А, страница в B уже загрузилась, и функция `f` в ней уже существует. А в некоторых - нет.

Используйте:

```
<p>Фрейм A</p>
<a href='#1'>f2</a>
<script>
    var f2 = function () { return parent.B.f(); };
    var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    aTag[0].addEventListener('click', f2, false);
</script>
```

*Update*

Минутку, Вы же не вызываете сами `f2()`. Строка в Вашем коде

```
var f2 = return parent.B.f;
```

присваивает `f2` значение `undefined`, если страница в B еще не загрузилась, а потом это `undefined` подается в `addEventListener`, где оно просто игнорируется.

В случае с

```
var f2 = function () { return parent.B.f(); };
```

обращение к функции `f` из страницы фрейма B, происходит, когда пользователь щелкает по ссылке - к этому времени обе страницы уже давно загрузились. А в `addEventListener` мы подаем функцию определенную здесь же - в странице А.

Comment: Игорь, если можно, еще вопрос, в случае когда страница В не загрузилась, почему f2() не возвращает undefined?

Comment: @ОлегСухих Добавил в ответ.

Comment: отличное решение проблемы. Я пытался решить ее повторной перезаргузкой фрейма А, заметив что перезагрузив его вручную - получал нужный результат. Не знал, про "произвольную загрузку".